# Use laptop and external monitor at the same time using NVIDIA X Server

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor, intel, nouveau

I managed to setup the display properties for the monitor via `xorg.conf` file, but I can't seem to find a way to use both external and built-in laptop monitor at the same time. Here is my `xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 390.42  (buildd@lcy01-amd64-029)  Thu Mar 22 17:34:03 UTC 2018

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 390.48  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-07)  Thu Mar 22 01:07:32 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" Below "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960M"
    Screen         0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "intel"
    Option         "AccelMethod" "sna"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen         1
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "SAMSUNG"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    HorizSync       26.0 - 81.0
    VertRefresh     24.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    Option         "DPI" "96 x 96"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseEdidDpi" "False"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "UseEdidDpi" "False"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1680x1050 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

With this settings, only the external monitor is working, but if I switch the lines `Screen 0` and `Screen 1` between the two `Section "Device"`, only laptop monitor is working.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem here: Only the HDMI external monitor is working, laptop screen is not. Using Fedora 32.

After many tested options, I managed to get it working with the following /etc/X11/xorg.conf. Please note that the key here is the **AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens** option. You need a graphics card that supports Prime Render Offloading for this (mine is a Nvidia GeForce RTX 2060):

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" LeftOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "dpms"   "on"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "dpms"   "on"
EndSection

Section "Device"    # This is the cool NVIDIA GPU
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    Screen         0
EndSection

Section "Device"   # This is the built-in GPU
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "modesetting"
    BusID          "PCI:0:2:0"
    Screen         1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection
```